# Differentiability of norm $\|x\|_1$ at $x=(1,0)$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

How can I prove that $\|x\|_1:= |x_1|+|x_2|$ is not differentiable at $x=(1,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ??

Comment: The absolute value function is not differentiable at zero. Then I assume that from the definition of derivative of a map from $\Bbb R^2\to [0,\infty)$ you must achieve the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Examine the existence of partial derivates of $f(x_1,x_2)=|x_1|+|x_2|$ at $(1,0)$.

If one or both of them don't exist, that implies that $f$ is not differentiable at $(1,0)$.